# Request Azure function from Azure APIM when I set the function's auth level as FUNCTION

Tags: azure-functions, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I imported apis from Azure Function to my apim, it can successful access the function without append the parameter named 'code'.
But when I tried to access the function directly used the function's domain, it indeed need append the code parameter.
Is there any setting error, or the apim can access Azure function without code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accessing the Function App Url directly, you would need to pass the code in the query string. After importing the functions into API Management resource, then you need not pass the code, instead you need to pass a http header `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` with subscription key value.